# Specifying optional dependencies in pypi python setup.py

Tags: python, setup.py, pypi

How do I specify optional dependencies in python's `setup.py` ?

Here's my stab at specifying an optional dependency for an open source library of mine but it doesn't seem to do much.

https://github.com/od-eon/django-cherrypy/blob/master/setup.py

Specifically `extra_requires` in this snippet:

```
setup(
    name='django-cherrypy',
    version='0.1',
    packages=packages,
    license='LICENSE',
    description='cherrypy, running under django',
    long_description=open('README.md').read(),
    author='Calvin Cheng',
    author_email='calvin@calvinx.com',
    install_requires=['cherrypy-wsgiserver'],
    extra_requires=['newrelic'],
    url='https://github.com/od-eon/django-cherrypy',
)
```

Suggestions?

Comment: Any one else find the term "optional dependencies" funny? I do.

Comment: Funny it may be, but it sure makes a lot of sense. You may design optional features that will be disabled if the lib is not there (eg., an optimization) without breaking anything in the program. More commonly, it's actually very handy to be able to declare **dev** dependencies, like [npm does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18875674).

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You've got an incorrect keyword. It's `extras_require`, and [it's supposed to be a dict.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45043494/547270)

```
setup(
    name="django-cherrypy",
    ...
    extras_require = {
        'mysterious_feature_x':  ["newrelic"]
    }
)
```

Comment: Thanks @voithos.  I should have rtfm. Your recommended link above (http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/setuptools#declaring-extras-optional-features-with-their-own-dependencies) helps a lot!

Comment: current setup tools docs on optional dependencies: https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/dependency_management.html#optional-dependencies