# What is the difference between `extras_require()` and `install_requires()` in setup.py?

Tags: python, setuptools, setup.py

I am trying to understand the difference between `extras_require()` and `install_requires()` in setup.py but haven't been able to get it. Both are used for installing Python dependencies, but what's the difference between them?

Answer (score 102):

According to the [setuptools documentation](http://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html),

> `extras_require`
> A dictionary mapping names of “extras” (optional features of your project) to strings or lists of strings specifying what other distributions must be installed to support those features.

and

> `install_requires`
> A string or list of strings specifying what other distributions need to be installed when this one is.

The section on [Declaring “Extras” (optional features with their own dependencies)](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/dependency_management.html?highlight=extras_require#optional-dependencies) elaborates on this:

> Sometimes a project has “recommended” dependencies, that are not required for all uses of the project. For example, a project might offer optional PDF output if ReportLab is installed, and reStructuredText support if docutils is installed. These optional features are called “extras”, and setuptools allows you to define their requirements as well. In this way, other projects that require these optional features can force the additional requirements to be installed, by naming the desired extras in their `install_requires`.

The biggest difference is that the requirements in `extras_require` are only installed as needed:

> These requirements will not be automatically installed unless another package depends on them (directly or indirectly) by including the desired “extras” in square brackets after the associated project name. (Or if the extras were listed in a requirement spec on the EasyInstall command line.)

So to summarize:

- If the dependency is **necessary** to run your project, put it in `install_requires`. They will always be installed.
- If your project has **optional features** which add dependencies, put those dependencies in `extras_require`. Those dependencies will **not** be installed unless that feature is called for by the user or another package.

Comment: To [install the extras](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13681679/1088938) you can use something like `pip install 'package[extra]'`.

Comment: nice [docs](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide/dependency_management.html?highlight=extras_require#optional-dependencies) for `extras_require` and `install_requires`

Answer (score 37):

`install_requires` are the dependency packages which are installed no matter what.

```
pip install mypackage
```

`extras_require` are optional, and need to be specified at install time.
This is a feature of `pip`.

```
pip install "mypackage[extra]"
pip install "mypackage[develop]"
pip install "mypackage[extra,develop]"
```

Two examples: [polars](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/) and [imgui](https://pypi.org/project/imgui/) allow you to specifiy extra dependencies or a graphics backend:

```
pip install "polars[all]"
pip install "polars[numpy,pandas,pyarrow]"

pip install "imgui[pygame]"
pip install "imgui[full]"
```

Refer to [PEP 508](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0508/) to see all possible selectors you can use; e.g. `; python_version < "2.7"`.

Answer (score 20):

I'm not sure of the official usage, but I use `extras_require()` to specify conditional dependencies.

In my case -

```
extras_require={":python_version<'3.5'": ["scandir"]}
```

Theoretically, this should be available via `install_requires()` itself, but it only works as it should starting version X.XX (several claims as to which version starts getting it right) of `setuptools`.

This article explains it nicely: [Conditional Python Dependencies](https://hynek.me/articles/conditional-python-dependencies/)

Comment: "version X.XX" is "at least version [20.5](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/history.html#id283)" or maybe even "at least [v36.2.0](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/history.html#v36-2-0)", as far as I can tell.