# Create different python packages from same repository

Tags: python, repository, setuptools, python-packaging

I'm building a Python package from a source code repository I have, using a `setup.py` script with `setuptools.setup(...)`. In this function call I include all the Python libraries needed for the project to be installed using the `install_requires` argument.

However, I noticed some users do not use all the sub-packages from this package, but only some specific ones, which do not need some libraries that are huge to be installed (e.g., torch).

Given this situation, can I create in the same repository something like `myrepo['full']` or `myrepo['little']`? Do you have any document on how to do so if it's possible?

Comment: `extras_require` See https://stackoverflow.com/a/45043494/7976758 and https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/dependency_management.html#optional-dependencies (switch the docs to `setup.py`).

Comment: if you write it as an answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called optional dependencies and is implemented using `extras_require`. It's a dictionary mapping names to lists of strings specifying what other distributions must be installed to support those features. For example:

```py
setup(
    name="MyPackage",
    ...,
    extras_require={
        'little': ['dep1', 'dep2'],
        'full': ['dep1', 'dep2', 'torch'],
    },
)
```

To avoid repeating lists of common dependencies:

```py
common_deps = ['dep1', 'dep2']

setup(
    name="MyPackage",
    ...,
    extras_require={
        'little': common_deps,
        'full': common_deps + ['torch'],
    },
)
```

See the docs at https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/dependency_management.html#optional-dependencies. Switch the docs to `setup.py` in the menu.

Comment: in case you need to install it from git after doing this change, you can select the version with https://stackoverflow.com/a/30239714/1200914