# How to write setup.py so that different submodules/extra packages can be installed separately?

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, setup.py, airflow

Using Airflow as an example, a user is able to install "extra packages"/submodules:

https://airflow.incubator.apache.org/installation.html#extra-packages

How to write setup.py so that different submodules can be included in the module install?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Specifying optional dependencies in pypi python setup.py](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10572603/specifying-optional-dependencies-in-pypi-python-setup-py)